# Choose from two tables with parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new to this stored procedure business and I believe this is straight forward just not familiar with the syntax or how to return.

I'm passing in a parameter ID, and I would like to return information on that ID, but it could be from one of two tables.  Depending on the table depends on which columns I return.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE name
 @ID varchar (40)
AS

BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @result int

 IF exists (SELECT id, name, state
  FROM tab1
  WHERE tab1.id = @ID
 ) 
  begin
  /* return somehow, maybe as a temp table from previous check */
 end
 else ( SELECT id, name, country, state      
  FROM tab2
  WHERE tab2.id = @ID
 )
 begin
  /* return information from tab2 instead */
 end
end
go
```

Is checking if they exist in a table the best way, or should this really be a join? My sql skills are new, and I'm not sure what's available within stored procedures.

How is it that I return the information? 
My java accessing it is expecting this as the second result set within this procedure.  (No I don't have the first result set figured out) The first resultset will be much the same, checking between two tables stored in different databases but will involve a bit more, I just wanted this one working first.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What would you do if the same ID appeared in both tables?

Comment: The ID should be unique across both tables.  One would be for national, and the other international people. I got it to work fine by repeating the select statement, but wouldn't this 'double' the time, and couldn't it be faster with storing it as a temp?  So 
`INTO #tmpNA` and then retrieve with `SELECT * FROM #tmp NA`

Comment: No there is no need for a temp table.it will add an extra step and will slow the query

Comment: You might examine your basic design. It seems to me that national and international all have a country property. Why not combine the tables into one, and select According to country? Seems like you are doing twice the work for minimal or no performance gain. How many records are we dealing with here?

Comment: Thanks @ClearLogic I was not sure if a temp would add overhead or just doing the query again.
XIVSolution it's not my design sadly, just what I work with. It has to deal with who has to contact each I believe.  Thanks for the concern though

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning same columns from both tables you can do like this. Data from table2 will only get selected if not exists in table1.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE name
 @ID varchar (40)
AS

BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @result int

 SELECT id, name, state , country FROM tab1  WHERE tab1.id = @ID
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, name,state  , country   FROM tab2  WHERE tab2.id = @ID
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tab1 WHERE tab1.id=@ID )
```

Comment: _Depending on the table depends on which columns I return._  They will not be the same columns thank you though.